# XSL - remove specific Comments (Keyword)

Tags: xml, xslt, comments

i have a general Question about XSL-Transformation. We currently have the Problem that we wont to make the first Steps into a Continuous-Delivery System. So basically there are few things to Change in the Deployment Scripts. One point is to Transform configs just as web.config. My Problem is, that we are using those web.configs with different kinds of comments. Like for testing different options etc. For that we also have Comments which are relevant for the Team in Production environment to switch different options. Those Comments are very relevant and we don't want to delete them in the process of Transformation.
So the question is: Is it possible to Transform/Copy only Comments with a specific Keyword in it (like "Prod") with XSL Transformation?

And if yes how? I Only found Topics to delete all Comments.

Thanks for your help
Rosch

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the identity transformation

```
<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
  <xsl:copy>
    <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
  </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
```

and

```
<xsl:template match="comment()[not(contains(., 'Prod'))]"/>
```

which ensures comments not containing `Prod` are not copied.